# How represent each mips instruction line in c++ struct?

Tags: c++, c, mips, cpu-architecture

I am trying to simulate virtual MIPS architecture using c++. During this process I have to store each line of mips architecture as struct and store it into vector so I can simulate 5 stages of pipeline.
My problem is, how can I represent each line of instruction, eg:

```
Loop: ST R1 R2 //store to M[R2] the contents of R1
ADD R1 R2 R3  // R1 R2 and R3 are register
SUB R1 1
BRNZ  R1 Loop //if R1 is not 0 then loop
```

Each line looks different and I am trying to find a generic way to represent this in struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look in how these instructions are implemented in hardware. First of all MIPS is a [RISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) architecture, and this comes at your help, since all instructions have the same length.

Then MIPS has three instruction types, which are summarized in this image:

[image]

Starting from this you can easily develop your own structure by using bit packed instructions together with unions:

```
struct Instruction {
  u8 opcode : 6;
  union {
    struct {
      u8 rs : 5;
      u8 rt : 5;
      u16 imm;
    } i;
    struct {
      u8 rs : 5;
      u8 rt : 5;
      u8 rd : 5;
      u8 shift : 5;
      u8 funct : 6;
    } r;
    struct {
      u32 address : 24;
    } j;
  }
};
```

In this way you can access any specific instruction type easily

Instruction instruction;

```
i.i.rs = ..
i.i.rt = ..
i.i.imm = ..
```

Mind that if you keep opcode separated from the 3 structs inside the `union` (instead that replicating it) the padding will enforce a larger size for the whole `struct`, compared to the real hardware but this shouldn't be an issue in your case.

Comment: hey jack thank you very much for the answer. But I still have some doubt on how to include the LABEL ?? ( Loop:). Should I include in same struct or different struct. If I include in different struct I get confused on how to manage that. @Jack

Comment: The label doesn't exist in MIPS, the label must be resolved prior the assembly phase. You need to first create a map from labels to instructions then you will resolve the labels and replace the corresponding jump with the correct address.